# Using Espresso to test drawable changes

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm new to Espresso testing, but there doesn't seem like there's any way to test drawable changes.

I have a tutorial that is an `ImageView` `Drawable` slideshow 'tucked into' a semi-transparent `TextView`. In my tests, I want to ensure that when the next button is pressed, the proper `Drawable` has been inserted into the tutorial's `ImageView`.

There is no default `Matcher` to check for `Drawable`s, so I set out to write my own using https://stackoverflow.com/a/28785178/981242. Unfortunately, since there is no way to retrieve the id of an `ImageView`'s active `Drawable`, I can't complete the `matchesSafely()` implementation.

This can't be the only use case for testing active `Drawable`s. What is the tool that people normally use for situations like this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I prefer not to compare bitmaps and instead follow this answer's advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14474954/1396068

When setting the image view's drawable, also store the drawable ID in its tag with `setTag(R.drawable.your_drawable)`. Then use Espresso's `withTagValue(equalTo(R.drawable.your_drawable))` matchers to check for the correct tag.

Comment: Just to add the full withTagValue code: `withTagValue(CoreMatchers.<Object>equalTo(R.drawable.your_drawable))));`. Thanks. :)

Comment: Theres just one problem with this solution - you need to add code in production that will be only used in tests  and thats a big no-no.

Comment: and you may remove the actual background and keep the tag, your UI test would still work and would not reflect the reality

Comment: Can you explain the disadvantages of comparing Bitmaps?

Comment: if you change a single color, padding or font, the test will fail and you'll have to update the bitmap. That's brittle and a lot of work and will happen frequently @MohamedKhaled

Answer (score 12):

please check this tutorial I found.
Seems to work pretty good https://medium.com/@dbottillo/android-ui-test-espresso-matcher-for-imageview-1a28c832626f#.4snjg8frw

Here is the summary  for copy pasta ;-)

```
public class DrawableMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<View> {

    private final int expectedId;
    String resourceName;

    public DrawableMatcher(int expectedId) {
        super(View.class);
        this.expectedId = expectedId;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(View target) {
        if (!(target instanceof ImageView)){
            return false;
        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) target;
        if (expectedId < 0){
            return imageView.getDrawable() == null;
        }
        Resources resources = target.getContext().getResources();
        Drawable expectedDrawable = resources.getDrawable(expectedId);
        resourceName = resources.getResourceEntryName(expectedId);

        if (expectedDrawable == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Bitmap otherBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) expectedDrawable).getBitmap();
        return bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap);
    }


    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with drawable from resource id: ");
        description.appendValue(expectedId);
        if (resourceName != null) {
            description.appendText("[");
            description.appendText(resourceName);
            description.appendText("]");
        }
    }
}
```

Please be aware that this only works when your `Drawable` is a `BitmapDrawable`. If you also have `VectorDrawable` or other `Drawable` you have to check for this (`imageView.getDrawable() instanceOf XXXDrawable`) and get the bitmap out of it. Except you have some kind of simple Drawable where you just have one color or so you can compare.

To get the Bitmap of a VectorDrawable for example you have to draw the VectorDrawable to a canvas and save it to a bitmap (I had some trouble when the VectorDrawable was tinted). 
If you have a StateListDrawable you can get the Drawable of the selected state and repeat your if instanceOf cascade.
For other Drawable types I don't have any experience, sorry!

Comment: This will not work if your `Drawable` is not `BitmapDrawable` which may be  `GradientDrawable`, `ColorDrawable` or `ShapeDrawable` and many others

Comment: For comparing Vector Drawable, a simpler way is to use getConstantState(). Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/comparing-two-drawables-in-android. I have tested it on simple vector drawables (from the material design icons collection), and it works well for them.

Answer (score 9):

There is one gist which contains `withBackground()`, `withCompoundDrawable()`, `withImageDrawable()` matchers from [Frankie Sardo](https://gist.github.com/frankiesardo/7490059). All credits to him.

And regarding image ids - you can type `R.drawable.image_name`, then the id of the drawable will be retrieved automatically.

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 7):

Based on @wolle and @FreewheelNat's help, for comparing (Vector) Drawable:

```
public static Matcher<View> withDrawableId(@DrawableRes final int id) {
    return new DrawableMatcher(id);
}


public static class DrawableMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<View> {

    private final int expectedId;
    private String resourceName;

    public DrawableMatcher(@DrawableRes int expectedId) {
        super(View.class);
        this.expectedId = expectedId;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(View target) {
        if (!(target instanceof ImageView)) {
            return false;
        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) target;
        if (expectedId < 0) {
            return imageView.getDrawable() == null;
        }
        Resources resources = target.getContext().getResources();
        Drawable expectedDrawable = resources.getDrawable(expectedId);
        resourceName = resources.getResourceEntryName(expectedId);
        if (expectedDrawable != null && expectedDrawable.getConstantState() != null) {
            return expectedDrawable.getConstantState().equals(
                    imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState()
            );
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with drawable from resource id: ");
        description.appendValue(expectedId);
        if (resourceName != null) {
            description.appendText("[");
            description.appendText(resourceName);
            description.appendText("]");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Kotlin version of @drakeet's answer with a few modifications.

```
class DrawableMatcher(private val targetContext: Context,
                  @param:DrawableRes private val expectedId: Int) : TypeSafeMatcher<View>(View::class.java) {

override fun matchesSafely(target: View): Boolean {
    val drawable: Drawable? = when(target) {
        is ActionMenuItemView -> target.itemData.icon
        is ImageView -> target.drawable
        else -> null
    }
    requireNotNull(drawable)
    
    val resources: Resources = target.context.resources
    val expectedDrawable: Drawable? = resources.getDrawable(expectedId, targetContext.theme)
    return expectedDrawable?.constantState?.let { it == drawable.constantState } ?: false
}

override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
    description.appendText("with drawable from resource id: $expectedId")
    targetContext.resources.getResourceEntryName(expectedId)?.let { description.appendText("[$it]") }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I accept the answer of @wolle as valid, but I would like to admit that, even for Java, it could be even **simpler** than that. It can be converted into a `static function` (or a `companion` in Kotlin) and also clean some **deprecated code**.

Anyway, the code-compacted-non-deprecated solution for Kotlin would be this:

```
    fun drawableIsCorrect(@DrawableRes drawableResId: Int): Matcher<View> {
        return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                description.appendText("with drawable from resource id: ")
                description.appendValue(drawableResId)
            }

            override fun matchesSafely(target: View?): Boolean {
                if (target !is ImageView) {
                    return false
                }
                if (drawableResId < 0) {
                    return target.drawable == null
                }
                val expectedDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(target.context, drawableResId)
                        ?: return false

                val bitmap = (target.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                val otherBitmap = (expectedDrawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                return bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap)
            }
        }
    }
```

22 lines vs 44, eh?

Answer (score 0):

I already answered on the similar topic here: [Get the ID of a drawable in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49407083/5524413).
The approach is based on tagging a view with a specified resource id in the custom `LayoutInflater`. Whole process is automated by a simple library [TagView](https://github.com/shuhart/TagView). It's especially handy for Espresso test because you don't need to tag every view in your project manually. In fact, you don't need to change anything, except you set some drawables in runtime. In that case you need to look into [Tagging in runtime](https://github.com/shuhart/TagView#tagging-in-runtime) section.

As a result, you can compare two drawables just by their ids:

```
onView(withId(R.id.imageview)).check(assertTagKeyValue(
               ViewTag.IMAGEVIEW_SRC.id, android.R.drawable.ic_media_play));
```

Custom Espresso assertion `assertTagKeyValue` is available [here](https://github.com/shuhart/TagView/blob/master/sample/src/androidTest/java/com/shuhart/tagview/sample/ViewTagMatchers.java)

Comment: It gives you unresolved reference assertTagKeyValue

Answer (score 0):

```
fun withDrawableVector(@DrawableRes drawableResId: Int): Matcher<View> {
    return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("with drawable from resource id: ")
            description.appendValue(drawableResId)
        }
        override fun matchesSafely(target: View?): Boolean {
            if (target !is ImageView) {
                return false
            }
            if (drawableResId < 0) {
                return target.drawable == null
            }
            val expectedDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(target.context, drawableResId)
                ?: return false

            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                target.drawable.intrinsicWidth,
                target.drawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
             val newExpectedDrawable = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                expectedDrawable.intrinsicWidth,
                expectedDrawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            return bitmap.sameAs(newExpectedDrawable)
        }
    }
}
```