# Espresso how to test background image set via getWindow.setDrawable()

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing, instrumented-test

In my main activity I observe Livedata and change the background accordingly using `getWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable));`

My code:

```
backgroundImageViewModel.getBackgroundImageLive().observe(this, new Observer<BackgroundImage>() 
            @Override
            public void onChanged(BackgroundImage backgroundImage) {
                if(backgroundImage == null ||backgroundImage.getDrawable() == null) {
                    return;
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "drawable: " + backgroundImage.getDrawable());
                getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundImage.getDrawable());
            }
        });
```

In my espresso test, I update the live data. **But how can I test in if the background drawable changed?**

Comment: Dis you check this thread ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44538570/5132305

Comment: yes, I did, the difference is, that I am not checking any ImageView but the background which I set using ```getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()```