# Android Espresso check ImageButton background color

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-imagebutton

I´m new to Android Espresso testing, and in my application I have some `ImageButton` views that I would like to test their background colors but I could not achieve it by any means.

I tried using `ImageButton.imageTintList`, `ImageButton.backgroundTintList` and similar but to no success.

Is it even possible to retrieve the background color of an `ImageButton` view to use in custom view matchers?

Comment: See if the answer in this SO is enough to get your started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28743371/11625850

Comment: @agoff Already tried that, but `Button` and `ImageButton` are incompatible so that method does not work